# Argument error: cannot convert

Tags: c#, types, arguments

I wrote that in my `Main` method:

```
zeichnen.OpenField(spiel.testReturner, spiel.testReturnerZwei);
```

And the errors are: Argument 1:

- cannot convert from 'method group' to 'int[*,*]'
- Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'bool[*,*]'
- the best overloaded method match for 'Minesweeper.Draw.OpenField(int[*,*], bool[*,*])' has some invalid arguments

In my `Game` Class I have this:

```
public int testReturner()
{
    return _minenArray[5, 5];
}

public int testReturnerZwei()
{
    return _boolArray[5, 5];
}
```

And the method in my `Drawing` Class is this:

```
public void OpenField(int[,] minenArray, bool[,] boolArray)
```

The bool return in the `Game` Class has this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'

Comment: The type returned by your methods is `int`, if you do invoke them you'll have a type mismatch. `OpenField` expects `int[,]` adn `bool[,]`. As an aside, in general, avoid multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you aren't invoking the methods, and the methods' return values won't work with `OpenField`.

Try reworking your methods to look like this. This is an educated guess from the code you provided.

```
public int[,] testReturner()
{
  return new int[5, 5]; // or _minenArray
}

public bool[,] testReturnerZwei()
{
  return new bool[5, 5]; // or _boolArray
}
```

Comment: I already upvoted this, but I was hoping you were going to edit in some possible solutions?

Comment: Invoking will just get to the next error, see my comment. I guess thats another question.

Comment: @musefan i made an educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your Game class like this

```
public int[,] testReturner
{
  get{return _minenArray;}
}

public bool[,] testReturnerZwei
{
  get{return _boolArray;}
}
```

**UPDATE**
for use

```
zeichnen.OpenField(spiel.testReturner, spiel.testReturnerZwei);
```

Comment: yeah that worked thank you, but now I have these error:
-Non-invocable member 'Minesweeper.Game.testReturner' cannot be used like a method.
and 
-Non-invocable member 'Minesweeper.Game.testReturnerZwei' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: zeichnen.OpenField(spiel.testReturner(), spiel.testReturnerZwei());

it's on "testReturner" and "testReturnerZwei" in this line :/

Comment: @ThomasSteinbach for solve - not use this Properties as method :-), i.e. `testReturner` instead of `testReturner()`, and `testReturnerZwei` instead of `testReturnerZwei()`

Comment: would rate your answer up, but i don't have enough reputation haha

Answer (score 0):

You most likely wanted to write:

```
zeichnen.OpenField(spiel.testReturner(), spiel.testReturnerZwei());
```

You didn't invoke the methods.

Comment: ok, but there are still the same errors :/ why doesn't it work that way?

Comment: -1: Who upvoted this, it is wrong. The function return types do not match the argument types that are required

Comment: @musefan, but it could be what the OP ment.

Comment: @Jodrell: You think the OP meant to replace one compile error with another? I know they probably want to call the method, which is a start, but this change isn't enough. It still will not compile

Comment: @musefan the OP is asking what the errors mean. Not for our guesswork on what his code is supposed to do, and the best way to achieve that. How could we know from the code that is presented. I suppose we can assume that an exeception is undesirable but we can't accurately suggest the best way to fix it. Just a range of solutions that would compile.

Comment: @Jodrell: But this answer doesn't provide any explanation of what the errors mean, it's just a bit of code that wont compile

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this.

First, you're passing methods instead of actual parameters. Secondly, your `testReturner` and `testReturnerZwei` methods return SINGLE numeric values, while the method `OpenField` you're trying to invoke requires an array of integer values and an array of boolean values.

Without knowing the exact context and what you're trying to do it's difficult to tell what needs to be done to make your code work EXACTLY the way you want it.

Here's my quick suggestion:

```
public int[,] testReturner
{
    //assuming _minenArray is an array of arrays, as you still need to return an array
    get { return _minenArray[5, 5]; }
}

public bool[,] testReturnerZwei
{
    //assuming _boolArray is an array of arrays, as you still need to return an array
    get { return _boolArray[5, 5]; }
}
```

This will convert `testReturner` and `testReturnerZwei` from methods into parameters. Also, note the comments in the code.

Comment: see comment to my answer :-)

Comment: @Grundy Without knowing what _boolArray and _minenArray really are, it's a bit of guesswork...

Comment: it's hard not to agree

Answer (score -1):

```
public int testReturner()
{
  return _minenArray[5, 5];
}

public bool testReturnerZwei()
{
  return _boolArray[5, 5];
}
```

replace with this, it is type conversion error, you given int in place of bool.

Comment: although you have made a good point, it still wont solve the issue. It won't even compile